# In what sense is ''Oppenheimer-Snyder collapse a time reversed closed FRW model"?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, black-holes, gravitational-collapse

In what sense is ''Oppenheimer-Snyder collapse a time reversed closed FRW model" ?

That is, "Are closed FRW metric (k=1) and the geometry inside the collapsing homogeneous matter same?" If yes, how?

(FRW metric: $ds^2= -dt^2 + \frac{a^2(t)}{1-r^2}dr^2 + a^2r^2d\Omega^2$

OS metric: $ds^2= -e^\nu dt^2 + e^\lambda dr^2 + r^2d\Omega^2$

It would be nice, if some rigorous mathematical arguments are provided.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this quote from? What part of it in particular are unclear?

Comment: The OS metric is an FRW geometry patched to a Schwarzschild geometry at the surface of the collapsing sphere. Can you make it clearer what exactly you are asking?

Comment: [Yes, it's the closed metric and this gives all the details](http://grwiki.physics.ncsu.edu/wiki/Oppenheimer-Snyder_Collapse).

Comment: Exactly how does that give all the details?